# Flutter - Unhandled Exception: Unhandled error type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'DateTime?'

Tags: json, flutter, freezed

I am using Freezed and json_annotation to serialize API objects.

```
@freezed
class Block with _$Block {
  const factory Order({
    @JsonKey(name: 'block_id') required String id,
    @JsonKey(name: 'sent_at') DateTime? sentAt,
    @JsonKey(name: 'created_at') DateTime? createdAt,
  }) = _Block;

  factory Block.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$BlockFromJson(json);
}
```

but sometimes, the API returns the wrong type, in this case, int instead of a string, which throughs an error.
Is there is a way to createdAt to null if it receives the wrong type instead of throwing an error?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your createdAt could be coming in as MillisecondsSinceEpoch.

It's usually best to make sure your datatype is always the same, but if your datasource is unknown then probably your best bet would be to except both Datatypes and sort later.

`@JsonKey(name: 'created_at') DateTime?|int? createdAt,`

```
if(createdAt is DateTime){
  //do something
} else if(createdAt is int){
  //do something
}
```